# How to add key:value pairs from a zipped list to multiple sub-dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I am trying to assign lists of values to keys within a nested dictionary.

My structure is dictionary = {key1: {key2: list}}

I create my dictionary using the following code

```
surfDict = {}

for i in range(1, number_of_cells + 1):
        
surfDict["surf"+str(i)] = {}
```

In this case I have 5 cells so generate 5 key1s inside the main dictionary.

Next, I prepare the next level of the dictionary. I have a list of frames, named framesList, which will serve as the key2s. Then I have a list of self-contained valuelists, containing 3 values I am interested in.

These two lists are arranged in order so if I zip them, I pair up what I want to be my key2:value pairs in the dictionary.

My issue is that my framesList **(newIntFrameslst)** contains 5 repeats of 26 integers. So for example [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3...... etc..]

The list of my valuelists **(surfValueslst)** is structured like so [[x, y, z], [x, y, z], [x, y, z], [x, y, z], [x, y, z] etc....]

I want to add each integer from the framesList as the key2 for my valuelists and have all of those individual dictionaries contained within each key1.

However, I only want one frame in each dictionary, with its corresponding valuelist. So for example {{surf1: {1: [x, y, z]}, {2: [x, y, z]}, {3: [x, y, z]}, {4: [x, y, z]} etc....}, {surf2: {1: [x, y, z]}, {2: [x, y, z]}, {3: [x, y, z]}, {4: [x, y, z]} etc....}...etc...}

To do this I have tried this code:

for i in range(1, number_of_cells + 1):

```
for frame, values in zip(newIntFrameslst, surfValueslst):

    if frame not in surfDict["surf"+str(i)]:

        surfDict["surf"+str(i)][frame] = values
    
    else:

        try:

          surfDict["surf"+str(i + 1)][frame] = values

        except:

            surfDict["surf"+str(number_of_cells)][frame] = values
```

However, this does not seem to work. It gives me the correct set of valuelists in the surf1 dictionary. However, the remaining 4 dictionaries all contain the last set of valuelists from my data. I tried other things as well but this is as close as I got.

Apologies if this seems very convoluted, I tried to give as much detail as possible to avoid being vague.

Comment: Can you give a small example of `newIntFrameslst` and `surfValueslst` ?

Comment: Sorry. newIntFrameslst is the framesList I mention in the post and surfValueslst is the list of valuelists. The x, y, z are floats. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand completely:

Here's the "outer" dictionary (`number_of_cells = 3` to make it more assessable):

```
number_of_cells = 3
surfDict = {}
for i in range(1, number_of_cells + 1):
    surfDict["surf" + str(i)] = {}
```

```
surfDict = {'surf1': {}, 'surf2': {}, 'surf3': {}}
```

Here are examples for `newIntFrameslst` and `surfValueslst` (both smaller, for the same reason):

```
newIntFrameslst = [i for i in range(1, 8) for _ in range(number_of_cells)]
surfValueslst = [[i+j for j in range(3)] for i in range(0, number_of_cells * 21, 3)]
```

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7]

[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20],
 [21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26], [27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32], [33, 34, 35], [36, 37, 38],
 [39, 40, 41], [42, 43, 44], [45, 46, 47], [48, 49, 50], [51, 52, 53], [54, 55, 56],
 [57, 58, 59], [60, 61, 62]]
```

Then this

```
for i, (frame, value) in enumerate(zip(newIntFrameslst, surfValueslst)):
    surfDict["surf" + str((i % number_of_cells) + 1)][frame] = value
```

leads to

```
surfDict = {
 'surf1': {1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [9, 10, 11], 3: [18, 19, 20], 4: [27, 28, 29], 5: [36, 37, 38], 6: [45, 46, 47], 7: [54, 55, 56]},
 'surf2': {1: [3, 4, 5], 2: [12, 13, 14], 3: [21, 22, 23], 4: [30, 31, 32], 5: [39, 40, 41], 6: [48, 49, 50], 7: [57, 58, 59]},
 'surf3': {1: [6, 7, 8], 2: [15, 16, 17], 3: [24, 25, 26], 4: [33, 34, 35], 5: [42, 43, 44], 6: [51, 52, 53], 7: [60, 61, 62]}
}
```

Is that what you are looking for? (This differs a bit from the expected result that you've described above. But I think your description isn't correct, because this kind of object isn't possible.)

Comment: That's perfect. Just what I needed. Never thought to use the modulo operator! Thanks.